# Matplotlib: Different views from plt.savefig() and manual saving

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pie-chart, figure

If I save my matplotlib figure with `plt.savefig('piechart.png')` I get this figure here:
Size: 800x600, 99 DPI

[image: piechart from plt.savefig()]

If I show my figure with `plt.show()` and manually save it as a .png with the savebutton I get this figure here:
Size: 1198x803, 99 DPI

[image: piechart from manually saving]

As you can see the first picture doesnt contain the legendcolors of the first piechart and the other legends are really displaced.

How do I get the same figure as in the second picture by using the `plt.savefig('piechart.png')` command?

Here is my MCVE code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


internCounter = 0
kundeCounter = 0
newCounter = 0
closedCounter = 0
developingCounter = 0
testingCounter = 0
tbdCounter = 0
HWCounter = 0
SWCounter = 0
tClosedCounter = 0
tOpenCounter = 0

plt.style.use('ggplot')
fig = plt.figure()
labels = ('new', 'closed', 'developing', 'testing', 'tbd')
sizes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
colors = ['#F5FC34', '#52FC34', '#FAAB23', '#237DFA', '#C863FA', ]
explode = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax1.set_title("Status")
ax1.legend(labels, bbox_to_anchor=(0.05, 0.8))

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)            
labels = ('Intern', 'Kunde')
sizes = [1,2]
colors = ['#FAF063', '#63BBFA']
explode = (0, 0) 
ax2.pie(sizes, explode=explode, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax2.set_title("Department")
ax2.legend(labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.65))

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)            
labels = ('HW', 'SW')
sizes = [1,2]
colors = ['#6A0D7D', '#503C3C']
explode = (0, 0) 
ax3.pie(sizes, explode=explode, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax3.set_title("Origin")
ax3.legend(labels, bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.6))

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)            
labels = ('Closed', 'Open')
sizes = [1,2]
colors = ['#58FB4C', '#F8183A']
explode = (0, 0) 
ax4.pie(sizes, explode=explode, colors=colors, autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax4.set_title("Closed-Status")
ax4.legend(labels, bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.65))

plt.savefig('piechart.png')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following gives me very similar appearance in "`show`" and in "`savefig`".  I rearranged your code just to help me look at it, but I believe there are two differences in mine that may help yours: Defining the figure size to make sure it has room for the legends, and using `bbox_inches="tight"` in the `savefig` call.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig, ((ax1,ax2),(ax3,ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(11,10))

labels1 = ('new', 'closed', 'developing', 'testing', 'tbd')
labels2 = ('Intern', 'Kunde')
labels3 = ('HW', 'SW')
labels4 = ('Closed', 'Open')

sizes1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sizes2 = [1,2]
sizes3 = [1,2]
sizes4 = [1,2]

colors1 = ['#F5FC34', '#52FC34', '#FAAB23', '#237DFA', '#C863FA', ]
colors2 = ['#FAF063', '#63BBFA']
colors3 = ['#6A0D7D', '#503C3C']
colors4 = ['#58FB4C', '#F8183A']

explode1 = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
explode2 = (0, 0) 
explode3 = (0, 0) 
explode4 = (0, 0) 

ax1.pie(sizes1, explode=explode1, colors=colors1, autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax2.pie(sizes2, explode=explode2, colors=colors2, autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax3.pie(sizes3, explode=explode3, colors=colors3, autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)
ax4.pie(sizes4, explode=explode4, colors=colors4, autopct='%1.1f%%',shadow=True, startangle=90)

ax1.set_title("Status")
ax2.set_title("Department")
ax3.set_title("Origin")
ax4.set_title("Closed-Status")

ax1.legend(labels1, bbox_to_anchor=(0.05, 0.8))
ax2.legend(labels2, bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.65))
ax3.legend(labels3, bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0.6))
ax4.legend(labels4, bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.65))

plt.show()

fig.savefig('/Users/ite1/Desktop/test.png', bbox_inches="tight")
```